# WCF UserName authentication with .Net, PHP and Delphi clients

Tags: wcf, authentication

I have a WCF service that hosted in IIS and I want to use UserName authentication. My clients are .Net, PHP and Delphi.

I don't want to use SSL or any certification.

How can I do that?

Comment: dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/379526/wcf-username-without-certificate ?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Can I do that with certification?

Comment: Yes, you can do almost anything you want to, if you're willing to supply a server-side certificate. I'll post an answer with more details.

Answer (score 0):

Per your comment, if you are willing to supply a certificate on the server side then what you want to do is very easy. The WS-Security standard implemented by WCF should be readily available to any client that implements a web-service-like interface.

For the basic, no-frills username authentication, with minimal code, you just need to set the  property configuration options, for example: 
    http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752233.aspx

If you don't want to use Windows usernames (your question somewhat implies that not everyone will have a Windows username and/or password) you can supply a custom username provider that performs whatever actions you want. Set up a service behavior configuration that looks like this:

```
<serviceCredentials>
  <serviceCertificate findValue="localhost" storeLocation="LocalMachine"
    x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
  <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" 
    customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="MyService.Auth, MyService" />
</serviceCredentials>
```

Then build a class that does this:

```
public class Auth : UserNamePasswordValidator
{
    public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
    {
    }
}
```

If the validation fails, you should throw some sort of `FaultException` from that method; otherwise WCF will assume that the combination is successful.

Comment: Thanks. My service is hosted on the internet and I can't setup anything. Is there a way to use x509 certification without installing it?